# xcode sigabrt error when using array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to get an array working on xcode 9.4.1 between viewcontrollers but keep getting a sigabrt error within part of the first few lines. When playing the simulation the segues that use the array information work, but the segues that don't rely on the array information or are linked to it in any way end up resulting in a SIGABRT error within the array's code. Anyone know what's going wrong?

This is the code;

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let VC = segue.destination as! ViewController_array

    if segue.identifier == "grade1"{
        VC.gradeLabel = "Grade 1"
        VC.display = "information goes here1"
    }

    if segue.identifier == "grade2"{
        VC.gradeLabel = "Grade 2"
        VC.display = "information goes here2"
    }
}
```

(and the last few lines continue on as such for each grade)
The error with the code is somewhere within the first line - the receiver on the other viewcontroller is perfectly fine and no other viewcontrollers relate to the same code, it's just something within this first one here.
The sender viewcontroller is named 'ViewController' and the receiver is 'ViewController_array'

The error message it's resulting in is;

```
objc[11314]: Class VCWeakObjectHolder is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace (0x12d8504d0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference (0x12c97ce38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10fee11f0) to 'test2.ViewController_array' (0x10d40a710).
2018-08-18 21:06:07.764832+1000 test2[11314:111648] Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10fee11f0) to 'test2.ViewController_array' (0x10d40a710).
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign class name

> ViewController_array

to the VC inside IB

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the error message:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10fee11f0) to 'test2.ViewController_array'
```

That means that the view controller, that you are trying to segue to, is an instance of the class `UIViewController` and not `ViewController_array`. [Forced casting](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23) `UIViewController` to `ViewController_array` will always fail since it is `ViewController_array` who is the subclass of `UIViewController`, not the other way around.

You have to make sure that you are setting the right view controller class in the identity inspector in the storyboard:

[image: identity inspector]